# IndexedDB not working in FireFox and IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, indexeddb

I have the latest versions of Firefox and IE, but the example in [html5rocks.com](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/indexeddb/todo/) is not working in these two browsers.  I tested with Chrome and it works fine.
I have noted that these browsers does not fire any event ('onsuccess' or 'onerror') on attempting to open the indexedDB as follows.

```
var request = indexedDB.open("todos");
```

Please share any ideas/solution for this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

to make html5rocks demo work on Firefox you need to attach `onupgradeneeded` event on database open instead of `setversion` method for creating the database. 
here is the code sample that works both on Firefox and Chrome:

```
myStorage.indexedDB.open = function() {
  var v = 1;
  var request = indexedDB.open("todos", v);

  //Firefox code for db init
  request.onupgradeneeded = function (e) {
    myStorage.indexedDB.db = e.target.result;
    var db = myStorage.indexedDB.db;
    // We can only create Object stores in a setVersion transaction;

    if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("todo")) {
        var storeReq = db.deleteObjectStore("todo");
    }

    var store = db.createObjectStore("todo",
        {keyPath: "timeStamp"});

  }

  request.onsuccess = function(e) {
    myStorage.indexedDB.db = e.target.result;
    var db = myStorage.indexedDB.db;

    //Chrome code for db init
    if (v!= db.version && db.setVersion) {
      var setVrequest = db.setVersion(v);

      // onsuccess is the only place we can create Object Stores
      setVrequest.onerror = myStorage.indexedDB.onerror;
      setVrequest.onsuccess = function(e) {
        if(db.objectStoreNames.contains("todo")) {
          db.deleteObjectStore("todo");
        }

        var store = db.createObjectStore("todo",
          {keyPath: "timeStamp"});

        myStorage.indexedDB.getAllTodoItems();
      };
    }
    else 
        myStorage.indexedDB.getAllTodoItems();
  };

  request.onerror = myStorage.indexedDB.onerror;
}
```

Edit: Here is a link to working version of the html5roks ToDo demo, which I maintain on [github](https://github.com/denimf/IndexedDbToDo), expanded with two new features for viewing details data and updating values.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome is behind on the IndexedDB standard.

There was a new revision introduced in December and Firefox and IE have upgraded. Chrome has not yet.

I believe it's mostly folks from the Chrome crew who run HTML5Rocks.com so it makes sense why these examples would be behind.

The big change between the pre and post-December 2010 API are the change in `setVersion` requests and the new `onupgradeneeded` callback.

Comment: @JaimeOlivares: That's not the point, this is about the support for the *newest version* of the spec. `IDBDatabase.setVersion()` has been [dropped from the spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/IndexedDB/IDBDatabase#setVersion%28%29_.0ADeprecated). But the example on html5rocks.com still uses it. So this answer seems to be correct.

Comment: Jaime, did you able to run the IndexedDB on Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

IndexedDB is not supported on IE. Visit html5test.com for verification

Edit 2015: IndexedDB API is [available in IE](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) as of version 10

Comment: This is completely untrue. IE has always supported the IDB standard and is in fact a major proponent of it. Their [Interoperability Labs](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/) is perhaps the most thorough example set on the net.

Comment: really? then why it is not passing the test? the fact that their are a propponent doesn't mean that it is currently implemented. As far as I can see, they are planning to introduce it in next version of IE.

Comment: @editor, According to [Microsoft HTML5 Labs](http://html5labs.interoperabilitybridges.com/prototypes/indexeddb/indexeddb/info) they are still in prototype phase. On the top of that, it is not passing the [Modernizr test](http://www.browserscope.org/user/tests/table/agt1YS1wcm9maWxlcnINCxIEVGVzdBib2KQGDA) which is the most used library to test HTML5 features. So, please review the facts before downvoting me.

Comment: Websockets, File API, etc. are all "prototypes." If your argument held water, it would be accurate to say IE doesn't support HTML5, which (just like your answer) is also wildly untrue.

Comment: I am not saying that, please don't make up your comment. I just said: **The current version of IE (9) does not support IndexedDB**, which is easily demonstrable. All other arguments are off-topic.

Comment: You wrote, "IndexedDB is not supported on IE." Let's agree to disagree but to me that's doesn't have the same meaning as your statement above.

Comment: yes, it is not supported on IE, because the current version does not support it. That should be enough for the asker. As we say in spanish: "a buen entendedor, pocas palabras". So, please don't make a chat here, it is not supported by the SO policy.

Answer (score 0):

Todo list example is outdated IndexedDB specification implemented on chrome. Now you got to use onupgardedneeded method, and well setVersion too for now.